# In-app purchase bug, not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, swift5

I am trying to implement In-app purchase in my app, but it doesn't work the way I want it to. I just run a test, and what happens is that when I press the `upgradeButton`, I get asked to type in my password(and it says that is it sandbox mode). When I press OK and wait a few seconds, it says that I already have purchased this, and will get it for free. When I then press the OK button, nothing happens. The `upgradeLabel` just says `PLEASE WAIT...` Not even the `YAY` log from `unlockProFeatures` is shown, so it looks like the `unlockProFeatures` does not run.

Please help. Does anyone have any clue what is wrong? Here you have my full `InfoViewController.swift` code:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class InfoViewController: UIViewController, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    var pro = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUpgraded")

    @IBOutlet var upgradeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var upgradeButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var restorebutton: UIButton!

    var productID = "com.myID.Upgrade"
    var productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Setup UIView:

        if pro {
            upgradeButton.isEnabled = false
            restorebutton.isHidden = true
            upgradeLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("SUBSCRIPTION: PREMIUM", comment: "")

        } else {
            upgradeButton.isEnabled = true
            upgradeLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("UPGRADE TO PREMIUM", comment: "")

            // In App Purchase:
            print("IAP: Loading...")
            upgradeButton.isEnabled = false

            self.configureIAP()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func upgradeButtonAction(_ sender: Any) { // Purchase button
        print("Upgrade button tapped")

        upgradeButton.isEnabled = false

        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            print("canMakePayments")

            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)

            let paymentRequest = SKMutablePayment()
            paymentRequest.productIdentifier = productID
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(paymentRequest)

            upgradeButton.isEnabled = false
            upgradeLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("PLEASE WAIT...", comment: "")
        } else {
            print("User unable to make payments")
            upgradeButton.isEnabled = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func restoreButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Restore")

        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }

    func configureIAP() {

        // Set IAPS
        if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
            print("IAP is enabled, loading")

            let productIDSet:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "com.myID.Upgrade")
            productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIDSet as! Set<String>)
            productsRequest.delegate = self
            productsRequest.start()

            upgradeButton.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            print("please enable IAPS")
        }

    }

    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print("product request")
        let myProduct = response.products

        for product in myProduct {
            print("product added")
            print(product.productIdentifier)
            print(product.localizedTitle)
            print(product.localizedDescription)
            //println(product.price)

            //list.append(product )

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.upgradeButton.isEnabled = true
            }
            print("Upgrade now! (" + product.localizedPrice() + ")")
        }
    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, removedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("REMOVED")
    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            if transaction.transactionState == .purchased {
                //if item has been purchased
                print("Transaction Successful")
                creditsLabel.text = "Purchase Completed!"
                self.unlockProFeatures()
            } else if transaction.transactionState == .failed {
                print("Transaction Failed: \(String(describing: transaction.error))")
                upgradeButton.isEnabled = true
                upgradeLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("UPGRADE TO PREMIUM", comment: "")

                // create the alert
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: transaction.error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else if transaction.transactionState == .restored {
                print("Transaction Restored")
                creditsLabel.text = "Purchase Restored!"
                self.unlockProFeatures()
            } else if transaction.transactionState == .purchasing {
                print("purchasing")
            } else if transaction.transactionState == .deferred {
                print("deferred")
            }
        }
    }

    func unlockProFeatures(){

        print("YAY")

        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUpgraded")

        upgradeLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("SUBSCRIPTION: PREMIUM", comment: "")

    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried running this on an actual device ?

Comment: @JulianSilvestri Yes, that is what I am doing. I have it connected to my iPhone XS MAX.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue, but after adding this line of code at the end of my version of unlockProFeatures() I managed to get my in-app purchase working.

```
self.viewDidLoad()
```

Comment: But the `unlockProFeatures()` does not run at all.